# How to get all pages awaiting moderation in Wagtail

Tags: python-3.x, django, wagtail

I'm trying to find a way to query all pages that are currently awaiting moderation.

I tried `PageRevision.objects.filter(submitted_for_moderation=True).values('page_id')`, but it seems to return only a few of them, I don't understand why.

If i can get all pages in moderation, then i will be able to get what I really want : all pages awaiting moderation for the user currently logged in.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The `submitted_for_moderation` field is only used by the legacy moderation system that was [deprecated in Wagtail 2.10](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/releases/2.10.html#move-to-new-configurable-moderation-system-workflow) - pages submitted for moderation since then will use the [Workflow system](https://guide.wagtail.org/en-latest/how-to-guides/configure-workflows-for-moderation/).

The equivalent to your query would be:

```
PageRevision.objects.filter(task_states__status='in_progress').values('page_id')
```

From Wagtail 4.0 onward `PageRevision` [was replaced with a `Revision` model that covers snippet models too](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/releases/4.0.html#pagerevision-replaced-with-revision), so this will become:

```
Revision.page_revisions.filter(task_states__status='in_progress').values('object_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of Wagtail you are using but from the code provided, it looks like you are using the legacy moderation functionality. Please note that that is [deprecated and will be removed](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/releases/5.2.html#legacy-moderation-system-is-deprecated) completely in 2024. If you can upgrade, then the list of pages in moderation (aka in a workflow) will be automatically added to the dashboard for your users. (If you upgrade step by step, the system should automatically create a simple workflow that mimics the older moderation system.)

[image]